# ROS on Ubuntu Communicating with Win_ROS

Tags: ros, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am currently working on a robot that runs Windows 7. The control program is done using DirectX SDK 9.0 and Visual Studio 2008 Express. I am planing on using ROS for navigation. Now, the problem is communicating between the robot (Windows 7) and a workstation running Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS fuerte.

To get started, I was trying to get a publisher node on my Windows machine to publish to a Topic on my Ubuntu machine. I followed these instruction:

> • Installation
>
> 1. Download the latest ROSWIN32 installation executable  here or do a
>    svn checkout of the sources from
>    here.
> 2. Run the executable and complete the installation. Running the example
>    "babbler" 
>     • Setting up your Linux
>    machine.
> 3. We will first need to set ROS_IP. Open a terminal and enter the
>    following command.  `export ROS_IP=mylinuxipaddress`  Where
>    mylinuxipaddress is the IP address of
>    your linux machine.
> 4. Now we will fire up the ros master. In the same terminal enter the
>    following command.  `roscore`  Remember
>    the ROS_MASTER_URI after the master
>    has been launched successfully. You
>    will require this in the later steps.
> 5. Note: in order to avoid exporting ROS_IP every time you open a new
>    terminal, you can edit the environment
>    variable permanently by editing its
>    value in the ros/setup.sh file. 
>    • Setting up your Windows machine.
> 6. Copy the REC GmbH/ROSWIN32/examples folder from your installation
>    directory to a location where you have
>    write access (your Desktop for
>    instance.)
> 7. Create a build_babbler folder.
> 8. Start CMake and set the source directory to examples/babbler. Set the
>    build directory to build_babbler.
> 9. Press Configure and select the compiler "Visual Studio 9 2008". After
>    the configuration is complete, press
>    Configure once again. And then
>    finally, press Generate.
> 10. After successfully generating your visual studio project, navigate to the
>     build_babbler directory and open
>     babbler.sln with Visual Studio 2008.
> 11. You will now need to set the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP for windows
>     and this can be done by changing the
>     following two lines in the babbler.cpp
>     file. The ROS_MASTER_URI can be set by
>     modifying the following line to the
>     value we noted on the linux machine.
>      `ros::master::setURI("value obtained in the first section")`;
>     The ROS_IP can be set by modifying the
>     following line to include the IP
>     address of yourwindows machine.
>      `ros::network::setHost("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")` ;
> 12. Once the changes have been made, right click on babbler in the Solution
>     Explorer window and click build.
>     babbler should build without any
>     errors.
> 13. Make sure the master we started on the linux machine is still running.
> 14. Now, run babbler.exe from the build_babbler/Debug directory. A
>     babbler node will be initialized and
>     will start publishing string data on
>     the topic /babble
> 15. The other examples can be run in a similar way as babbler.

I can see the publisher node publishing on Win_ROS, but the Topic on my Ubuntu machine is not receiving it (checked using rxgraph). I have both machines on a local network.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue? Any help on communication in this way is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50507/ros-on-ubuntu-communicating-with-win_ros/) by [Merdad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3506/merdad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys, I resolved my problem by disabling Windows Firewall and using automatic IP assignment by the switch.

---

Originally posted by [Merdad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3506/merdad/) with karma: 40 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1